# Combobox in html and php

Tags: php, html

If the combobox select the **Archers** the browser will echo Correct but if the combobox will not select the **Archers** the browser will echo, i want to know if my syntax is wrong.

> Wrong. Error: Undefined index *text_hname*.

Here's the structure:

```
<form action="server.php" method="POST">
    <img src="images/logo.png" class="logo">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Account Details</h1>
            <br>
            <label class="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="text_username" class="text_user" placeholder="Enter username">
            <label class="password">Password</label>
            <input type="text" name="text_password" class="text_pass" placeholder="Enter password">
            <label class="email">Email</label>
            <input type="text" name="text_email" class="text_email" placeholder="Enter email">
            <label class="cname">Character Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="text_cname" class="text_cname" placeholder="Enter Character Name">
            <label class="character">Select Character</label>
            <select class="names" name="text_hname">
                <option>Archer</option>
                <option>Barbarian</option>
                <option>Balloon</option>
                <option>Witch</option>
                <option>Spirit</option>
                <option>Hog Rider</option>
                <option>Minion</option>
            </select>
            <img src="images/">
            <br>
            <input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit">


        </div>
    </form>


//option
$hero = $_POST['text_hname'];

if (isset($_POST['text_hname'])) {
    if ($hero == 'Archers') {
        echo "Correct";
    } else {
        echo "wrong";
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: Looks like you are referencing that array key before you know whether it exists. See [“Notice: Undefined index”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef). You might want to include your HTML code, as well.

Comment: Do you send the parameter text_hname to this file via POST?

Comment: @JulianSchmuckli i dont know :( im in beginner in this language. Im practicing at the moment.

Comment: @showdev i already edited

Comment: We can see that. Show us your form.

Comment: @j08691 i already edited

Comment: Also, "Archer" != "Archers".

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that if you're trying to assign $hero before you've checked if text_hname is set, it might not be defined.

Suggested refactor:

```
if (isset($_POST['text_hname'])) {
    $hero = $_POST['text_hname'];
    if ($hero == 'Archers') {
        echo "Correct";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "wrong";
    }
}
```

Comment: Surely it removes the error from your original unedited post though? Since you've edited it, the problem is clearly with your form not posting the value in the first place.

Comment: how the browser will echo the if statement if I select the archers? I will use javascript or no?

Comment: I'm not in front of my laptop now, so can't sort out your form right now, but it needs some work to make sure you are actually posting a value from your select element.

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST['text_hname']` will return the **selected** `option value` , not `option name` .

Modify your `select` like this:

```
<select class="names" name="text_hname">
    <option value="Archer">Archer</option>
    <option value="Barbarian">Barbarian</option>
    <option value="Balloon">Balloon</option>
    <option value="Witch">Witch</option>
    <option value="Spirit">Spirit</option>
    <option value="Hog_Rider">Hog Rider</option>
    <option value="Minion">Minion</option>
</select>
```

and `server.php` page

```
if (isset($_POST['text_hname'])) {

    $hero = trim($_POST['text_hname']); //** to remove any whitespace
    if ($hero == 'Archer') {
        echo "Correct";
    } else {
        echo "wrong";
    }
}
```

**EDIT** : it might be because your `$_POST['text_hname']` has whitespace. Try `trim()` on `$_POST['text_hname']`

Hope it's helpful.

Comment: Note that: "If [the value] attribute is omitted, the value is taken from the text content of the option element." -- [<option> @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option)

Answer (score 0):

```
//Your select in form needs values. Same values that you are going to compare.
<select class="names" name="text_hname">
    <option value="Archer">Archer</option>
    <option value="Barbarian">Barbarian</option>
    <option value="Balloon">Balloon</option>
    <option value="Witch">Witch</option>
    <option value="Spirit">Spirit</option>
    <option value="HogRider">Hog Rider</option>
    <option value="Minion">Minion</option>
</select>

//Php code
if (isset($_POST['text_hname'])) {
    $hero = $_POST['text_hname'];
    if ($hero == 'Archer') { //Its Archer, not Archers
        echo "Correct";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "wrong";
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that: "If [the value] attribute is omitted, the value is taken from the text content of the option element." -- [<option> @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option)